# How to capture cancel download event in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-broadcast, android-download-manager, android-broadcastreceiver

When file started download I am showing progress bar and if its completed I changed progress bar with successfully download icon. It works perfectly but the problem I am facing that if someone clicks of cancel button in notification tray it does not send broadcast which I have created to receive broadcast if file gets downloaded.

I am using DownloadManager to download the files and as we know in marshmallow we get an option to download files but how can I capture event of this cancel button.

Here is my code:

```
    <receiver android:name=".adapters.VideoListAdapter$VideoDownloadedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_CANCEL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

public static class VideoDownloadedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements AsyncResponse {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //perform event
        //works well if files gets completed but not if download gets cancel
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ACTION_DOWNLOAD_CLICKED will still be triggered, but when the download is canceled here is not cursor in the query.

Example of code in kotlin:

`private fun wasCanceled(downloadId: Long): Boolean {
            val cursor = downloadManager.query(DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId))
            return cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()
        }`